# Resolving font issue in chemfig

Tags: chemfig, mhchem

When writing chemical formula I use both `\chemfig{}` and `\ce{}` commands but I noticed that the two bring outputs having different font style as shown below.

[image]

Currently working with these codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{ITC Berkeley Oldstyle Std} 
\setmathsfont(Digits,Greek,Latin){ITC Berkeley Oldstyle Std} 
\begin{document}
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_3} different font from \ce{CH3CH2CH3} 
\end{document}
```

Kind help of how change the `chemfig` font to ITC Berkeley Oldstyle Std.

Comment: Try adding `\setmathrm{ITC Berkeley Oldstyle Std}`.

Comment: Background knowledge: mhchem's `\ce{}` uses the current text font. This is particularly useful for chemistry in section titles, where the text gets repeated in page headers and table of contents, each using another text font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `chemfig` package uses the following macro to print atoms:

```
\newcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
```

Therefore, since you already use `mathspec`, you should be able to select the font for atoms using `\setmathrm{ITC Berkeley Oldstyle Std}` in your preamble. You could of course also redefine the macro.

Comment: Respect @Jasper

Comment: and the community, in my main TeX I found this ! LaTeX error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.